# DatagramSocket event MessageReceived dosen't trigger

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Console Udp Server based on the System.Net.Sockets UdpClient from which I'm sending Udp Packets to the Ip of my Windows Phone 8.1.

The client on the phone uses Windows.Networking.Sockets DatagramSocket, my problem is that the event MessageReceived dosen't happen.

Source for DatagramSocket:https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241319

Comment: I don't know anything about this area, but I am inclined to think there's not enough information to investigate the problem. Are you initiating this UDP packet in code? If so, can we see that code?

Comment: We need to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

Took me ages to find the solution since it's pretty dumb: The DatagramSocket only **starts to receive after it has sent** something. (At least for broadcast messages.)

Some code: https://gist.github.com/michaelosthege/857acac92b8ee689a6bb30d5bf23d9f6

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help my application.  A little test server in node.js works receiving UDP with no fuss, but the C# stuff is way more complicated and just doesn't work.  Very frustrating.