# UWP DatagramsSocket doesn't not fire MessageReceived

Tags: sockets, uwp, udp

I'm working on a UWP application which should communicate via TCP/UDP to a remote device. My issue is that the UWP app successfully sends UDP messages to the remote device, but does not receive the replies.

Here follows the code extracted from the app (simplified):

```cs
async Task TestUdpIP()
{
    // Writer to the DatagramSocket
    DataWriter writer;

    using (var udpClient = new DatagramSocket())
    {
        try
        {
            // UDP Socket binding
            udpClient.MessageReceived += UdpClient_MessageReceived;
            var controllerName = new Windows.Networking.HostName(controllerIpAddress.ToString());
            await udpClient.BindEndpointAsync(controllerName, controllerIpPort.ToString());

            var remoteHostName = new Windows.Networking.HostName(hostIpAddres.ToString());
            await udpClient.ConnectAsync(remoteHostName, remoteHostPort.ToString());

            // Create a message to send
            string message = "Some message";

            // Reset the counter of messages received back from the remote robot
            messagesReceived = 0;

            // Send the message
            writer = new DataWriter(udpClient.OutputStream);
            writer.WriteString(message);
            await writer.StoreAsync();

            // Wait for robot status messages
            await Task.Delay(5000);              
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}

void UdpClient_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    // Just increment the number of messages received
    messagesReceived++;
}
```

However the `UdpClient_MessageReceived` handler does not fire. I'm sure that UDP messages are correctly sent from the UWP app and that the remote device replies back as shown in the following screenshot from [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) (the test has been taken on the same PC where the UWP app is running)

[image].

(IP Address, Port) details are shown in the following list to better explain the picture above

- UWP application: (192.168.1.108, 19000) to send and receive.
- Remote device:   (192.168.1.152, 15999) to receive and (192.168.1.152, 54697) to send

**Note:**  [this is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254106/datagramsocket-event-messagereceived-dosent-trigger), where the answer says that for whatever reason the `DatagramSocket` should fire some messages before being able to receive. In my example a message is sent out however the message received handler does not fire anyway.

**Note:** The UWP app has been granted the *internet (client)* and the *internet (client and server)* capabilities

**Note:** I've tried also this (more readable) approach to bind the inbound/outbound datagram socket on the UWP app obtaining the same results:

```cs
// UDP Socket binding
var controllerName = new HostName(controllerIpAddress.ToString());
var remoteHostName = new HostName(hostIpAddres.ToString());
EndpointPair endpointpar = new EndpointPair(controllerName,
                                            controllerIpPort.ToString(),
                                            remoteHostName,
                                            remoteHostPort.ToString());
udpClient.MessageReceived += UdpClient_MessageReceived;
await udpClient.ConnectAsync(endpointpar);
```

Where is the issue? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I came out with the idea of using two different `DatagramSocket` instances: one to send out UDP messages, and one to listen for incoming messages. With this code, I've been able to send UDP messages **to** the remote device (as before) and also I've been able to receive UDP messages **from** the remote device.

```cs
async Task TestUdpIP_DifferentPorts()
{
    // Writer to the DatagramSocket
    DataWriter writer;

    // Inbound and outbound DatagramSocket
    DatagramSocket udpListener = new DatagramSocket();
    DatagramSocket udpSender = new DatagramSocket();

    try
    {
        // String containing the serializaed message
        string serializedMessage = "Some message";

        var controllerName = new HostName(controllerIpAddress.ToString());
        var remoteHostName = new HostName(hostIpAddres.ToString());

        // Bind listener
        udpListener.MessageReceived += UdpClient_MessageReceived;
        await udpListener.BindEndpointAsync(controllerName, controllerIpPort.ToString());

        // Connect sender
        await udpSender.ConnectAsync(remoteHostName, remoteHostPort.ToString());

        // Reset the counter of messages received back from the remote robot
        messagesReceived = 0;

        // Send the message
        writer = new DataWriter(udpSender.OutputStream);
        writer.WriteString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
        await writer.StoreAsync();

        // Wait for robot status messages
         await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Some exception handling
    }

    udpSender.Dispose();
    udpListener.Dispose();

}

void UdpClient_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    // Just increment the number of messages received
    messagesReceived++;
}
```

With this approach only the IP port (or service name) of the inbound listener needs to be specified. The framework will choose the next available outbound IP port.

**Note:** If I understand well the `DatagramSocket.ConnectAsync(EndpointPair)` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocket#Methods), the same `DatagramSocket` instance can be used to send and listen for incoming message, so I could not figure out the need for two different instances. From the documentation:

> This `ConnectAsync(EndPointPair)` method on a `DatagramSocket` is used to define the local and remote endpoint where datagrams will be sent when using the `OutputStream` property. This method also restricts remote IP addresses of packets that will be accepted to the remote hostname in the endpointPair parameter. Only incoming packets that match the remote endpoint in the endpointPair parameter will trigger the `MessageReceived` event on the `DatagramSocket`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to also add the **Private Networks (Client & Server)** capability in your app's manifest.

On other hand, you can try the Official [DatagramSocket](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DatagramSocket) sample to see whether the both devices can communicate with each other.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. I will try your suggestions and report.

Comment: Hello @Breeze Liu. I've tried to add the **Private Networks (Client & Server)** capability to the UWP App, but nothing changed. I've also used for testing the DatagramSocket application: it came out that the remote device can exchange messages with the DatagramSocket application, and also the UWP app can exchange messages with the DatagramSocket application. But while the remote device can receive messages from the UWP app, the UWP app doesn't receive messages from the remote device... What a puzzle!

Comment: Ok. I managed to let it work. I decided to use two different `DatagramSocket` instances: one `udpSender` and one `udpListener`. Later I will post the full code.